# Safest way to get current page in Wordpress through $_SERVER

Tags: php, wordpress, server

I need to determine a redirect to another page very early in WP loading, specifically within `init` hook. For anyone familiar, at `init` hook, no global variables, like `$pagenow` or `$wpdb`, are set or initialized yet. So I have to rely on `$_SERVER` superglobal to determine the current page. But which of the various `$_SERVER` variables is the safest to use? I'm reading that some don't exist at specific environments. I checked mine, and I got the following results...

- `['REQUEST_URI']` <- current page, also contains the query string, ie. `/current-page/?some-query-string`
- `['REDIRECT_URL']` <- clean current page, ie. `/current-page/`
- `['SCRIPT_URI']` <- full URL, doesn't contain the query string, ie. `https://my-domain.tld/current-page/`
- `['SCRIPT_URL']` <- clean current page, ie. `/current-page/`
- `['REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URI']` <- full URL, doesn't contain the query string, ie. `https://my-domain.tld/current-page/`
- `['REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URL']` <- clean current page, ie. `/current-page/`

What I need is the current page, free of query-strings, etc, so anything like `REDIRECT_URL`, `SCRIPT_URL`, `REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URL` are fine, but which of the three is the safest to use?

Thank you in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to redirect a page to another page then you should use `template_redirect` action then you can check your page with the function `is_page` and then using `wp_safe_redirect` you can redirect your page to another page/url.